# How to easily push updates to a server?

Tags: playframework

Once I build my play application, what sort of tools could I use to automate the process of pushing the files to the server and then replacing my old code with the new one and restarting the server?

Is there anything out there that is already setup to work with play?

Comment: It's just a .jar/.war so you can use whatever you use to deploy a java app

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @nmat is correct.

> It's just a .jar/.war so you can use whatever you use to deploy a java app

For example, my team use [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).

There is documentation how to deploy to cloud services:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/DeployingCloud

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionHeroku

The only thing that I want to add is the special administration system that works with Lightband products, including play, **ConductR**:

https://conductr.lightbend.com/docs/2.1.x/Overview

https://conductr.lightbend.com/docs/2.1.x/ContinuousDeliverySetupOps

https://conductr.lightbend.com/docs/2.1.x/AkkaAndPlay#play25-conductr-bundle-lib

It helps to manage a set of services on a different servers with a different roles.